# Apple wireless keyboard without num keypad

Tags: keyboard

Does anyone know how to delete line breaks after text please?
I used to place the cursor after the last letter or symbol, take the page down to the bottom, and on the numeric keypad, hold down the delete key until the line breaks disappeared.
I've tried fn and backspace, but that doesn't take out the line breaks.

Comment: What program are you using?

Answer (score 2):

fn-delete (fn-⌫) should also be equivalent to forward delete (⌦).

Answer (score 0):

If you press the Delete key it removes content **after** the cursor, if you press the backspace key it removes content **before** the cursor.

That works on mine at least. But again knowing what program you are using it may have another shortcut that may be specific for that program itself.